# (React and Django) I am unable to delete an user from my userlist. (HTTP Status Code 404)

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, http-status-code-404, admin

I am following a tutorial, where I am attempting to delete an user from the user list as an Admin of the website. Even though it can be done from the django administration as well, in the tutorial we are trying to do this directly on the website itself. It is being done on the page, which is accessible only for the admin -
http://localhost:3000/admin/userlist

The thing is, that when I try to delete some user, (by clicking on an button, (icon) which is placed on the webpage) I am getting this error in my console -
xhr.js:177 DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/users/delete/3/ 404 (Not Found)

In my django terminal, I am getting this error -
Not Found: /api/users/delete/3/
[11/May/2021 09:57:38] "DELETE /api/users/delete/3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3479

Please take a look at the relevant parts of the codes - (I have triple checked the following codes with the ones, that are in the tutorial and they seem to be the same and that is why I would really appreciate some help, because it is working for my instructor, but not for me)

user_views.py -

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def getUsers(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

user_urls.py (inside urlpatterns) -

```
path('delete/<str:pk>', views.deleteUser, name='user-delete')
```

userConstants.js -

```
export const USER_DELETE_REQUEST = 'USER_DELETE_REQUEST'
export const USER_DELETE_SUCCESS = 'USER_DELETE_SUCCESS'
export const USER_DELETE_FAIL = 'USER_DELETE_FAIL'
```

userReducers.js - (constants USER_DELETE_REQUEST, USER_DELETE_SUCCESS and USER_DELETE_FAIL
have been imported to this file)

```
 export const userDeleteReducer = (state = { }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_DELETE_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }
        
        case USER_DELETE_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, success: true }

        case USER_DELETE_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }  

        default:
            return state    
     }
 }
```

userActions.js - (constants USER_DELETE_REQUEST, USER_DELETE_SUCCESS and USER_DELETE_FAIL have been imported to this file)

```
export const deleteUser = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {         //with the id we know, which user to delete
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DELETE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
      }, //only an admin can access this (view), so we need to be authenticated to actually access it
    };

    const { data } = await axios.delete(
      `/api/users/delete/${id}/`,
      config
    )

    dispatch({
      type: USER_DELETE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DELETE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

store.js - (the relevant one is - userDeleteReducer)

```
import { userLoginReducer, userRegisterReducer, userDetailsReducer, userUpdateProfileReducer, userListReducer, userDeleteReducer } from "./reducers/userReducers";
```

and (still inside store.js) (the relevant one is userDelete: userDeleteReducer)

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
  userList: userListReducer,
  userDelete: userDeleteReducer,

  orderCreate:orderCreateReducer,
  orderCreate: orderCreateReducer,
  orderDetails: orderDetailsReducer,
  orderPay: orderPayReducer,
  orderListMy: orderListMyReducer,
}); //stateName: nameOfTheReducer
```

UserListScreen.js -

```
import { listUsers, deleteUser } from "../actions/userActions";
```

and (still inside UserListScreen.js)

```
const userDelete = useSelector((state) => state.userDelete);
const { success: successDelete } = userDelete; //we are destructuring the userDelete
```

and (still inside UserListSreen.js)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin){
      dispatch(listUsers());
    }else{
      history.push('/login')
    }

  }, [dispatch, history, successDelete]); //dependencies

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {

      if(window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')){
        dispatch(deleteUser(id))
      }
      
  }
```

and (still inside UserListSreen.js)

```
<Button
  variant="danger"
  className="btn-sm"
  onClick={() => deleteHandler(user._id)}
>
  <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a forward slash in my user_urls.py file. (inside urlpatterns)

Instead of this -

```
path('delete/<str:pk>', views.deleteUser, name='user-delete')
```

There should be this -

```
path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteUser, name='user-delete')
```